# Using a CloudKit predicate to download specific record field

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have cloudKit records with large images and their thumbnails. I would like to query all the records and only download the thumbnails into a collection view, I will then download the larger images on selection.

I haven't worked with predicates much before, can someone please advise how I can structure one so that the CKQuery only downloads the Thumbnail. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with predicates.

You need to provide a value for the `desiredKeys` property of the `CKQueryOperation` to only retrieve specific fields such as the thumbnail.